# Where are W^Q,W^K and W^V matrices coming from in Attention model?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, natural-language

In the paper *Attention Is All You Need* the matrix of outputs is computed as follows:

[image]. 
   
In the blog post [The Illustrated Transformer](https://jalammar.github.io/illustrated-transformer/) it says that the matrices were trained during the process.

> So for each word, we create a Query vector, a Key vector, and a Value
>   vector. These vectors are created by multiplying the embedding by
>   three matrices **that we trained during the training process**

It is just not clear where do we get the WQ,WK and WV matrices that are used to create Q,K,V. All the resources explaining the model mention them if they are already pre-trained somewhere.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

K,Q and V are representations of encoder and decoder states and vary according to problem. The weight matrices correspond to the linear transformation of the states.They are trained as a part of the whole neural network block.
This blog might be helpful.
https://medium.com/lsc-psd/introduction-of-self-attention-layer-in-transformer-fc7bff63f3bc

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I was looking for.